# What's causing fb autologin on android, and how to "wait" for user login?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using phonegap/cordova 2.4 and the facebook plugin for cordova.

**Situation 1: open app as "not-logged-in-user" (=first time):**

app shows login button -> Login using facebook user & pass -> logout button is shown.

**Situation 2: open app a second time (previously logged in):**

app automatically logs the user in -> logout button in shown.

This is the behaviour I want, but I'm facing a problem:

I use jquery (`.hide()` and `.show()`) to hide the div's containing my login and logout button. The problem is, in situation 2, the login-div is shown for 1 or 2 seconds, because the code that regulates the showing and hiding of the divs is triggered at:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
```

**My question:**

How can I make sure the login button is only shown in situation 1, and not for 1-2 seconds in situation 2? I tried this:

```
function getLoginStatus() {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                                  if (response.status == 'connected') {
                                  //alert('logged in');
                                  } else {
                                  //alert('not logged in');
                                  $('#loggedin').hide();
                                   //show login button:
                          $('#loggedout').show();
                              $('#loading').hide();
                                  }
                                  });
            }
...
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

try {
//alert('Device is ready!');
FB.init({ appId: "xxx", nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
getLoginStatus();
...
```

The problem with getLoginStatus() is that, at the time this function is called, the user is in fact logged out. My app autologs in AFTER that. I need the autologin, but I wonder what's causing it... is it FB.init?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose best thing to do is save a Boolean on SharedPreferences that check for "Logged" or "Not Logged" and onCreate check for that, obviuosly faster than check through internet..

When you log first time and log goes right (id login_success)

```
if(login_success) {
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("bool_login",true);
 editor.commit();
}
```

Now when you create your activity, in onCreate method check for this value:

```
 onCreate() {
 if(getSharedPreferences("key",MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("bool_login",false)) {
     //True only if bool_login is true
    //hide your box for login
}
```

Hope that clarify